# Spring boot - Batch Update for hundred thousands of objects by a JPQL UPDATE query?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring boot 1.5.2 with Hibernate.

I have a list of objects. Each object contains many properties and @OneToMany relationships (i.e. it takes long time for fetching this object from database and updating this object to database).

That is why I use customized JPQL queries:

- One for loading the essential properties for the list of objects
- One for updating the needed properties for the object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = coverage)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Coverage implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = COLUMN_ID)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected long id;

    @Column(name = "coverage_id", unique = true)
    protected String coverageId;

    ... many more properties
}
```

And I have this method extends from CrudRepository for fetching the list of objects (with only the needed property)

```
@Transactional
public interface CoverageRepository extends CrudRepository<Coverage, String> {
    @Query("Select id, coverageId from Coverage")
    List<Object[]> readAllCoverageIdsAndTypes();

    @Modifying
    @Query("update Coverage set coverageId = :coverageId where id = :id")
    void saveCoverage(@Param("id") long id, @Param("coverageId") String coverageId);
}
```

Now, I want to update the coverageId of each Coverage object by this formula:

```
newCoverageId = coverageId + randomString.
```

So I have the list of Coverage objects with the updated **coverageId**. There are **100 000** of objects.

The way I'm doing is terribly slow:

```
    @Autowired
    CoverageRepository coverageRepository;
   
    @Transactional
    public void saveAllCoverages(List<Coverage> coverages) {
        for(Coverage coverage : coverages) {
           long id = coverage.getId();
           String newCoverageId = coverage.getCoverageId();
           this.coverageRepository.saveCoverage(id, newCoverageId);
        }
    }
```

**The performance is bad**, because Hibernate sends **an UPDATE query per iteration**. How can I make it faster? **I want** to send 100 queries for example (**batch update**) per transaction to postgresql.

Comment: Have you enabled batch updates? How large is your batch size. Depending on your database you might need some additional configuration to enable batching at all.

Comment: Is `randomString` actually a random String? If so I would check you database for a random function and do the complete update in the database without loading it.

Comment: @JensSchauder the randomSring is fetched from somewhere else, not be possible from database. So, I couldn't use the function from database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExecutorService.
[Full description here.](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial)

> **ExecutorService** is a JDK API that simplifies running tasks in asynchronous mode. Generally speaking, ExecutorService automatically
> provides a pool of threads and an API for assigning tasks to it. The
> easiest way to create ExecutorService is to use one of the factory
> methods of the Executors class.

For example, the following line of code will create a thread pool with 10 threads:

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); //init

executorService.execute(() -> YOUR_WORK_HERE);//usage
```